# Unable to use dynamic svg url in github Readme.md

Tags: github, svg, content-security-policy, readme

I am trying to use [this link](http://svg.ak1.io:8001?title=Hello&desc1=description1&desc2=description2) in my github readme.md file but not able to see it

after spending some time i got this error

*Refused to apply inline style because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src 'none'".*

Is there any way i can make it work either by modifying the svg or its usage

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your link does not work.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I have updated it, Please take a look.
Thanks